# What is the "value" of an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby

When I create a new object, it seems to have a "value", a representation that for example resides in a hash:

```
h = { str: String.new("asd") }  # => {:str=>"asd"}
```

or just in irb:

```
String.new("asd")
 => "asd"
```

How is that done? What is this "asd"?

When I create my own class:

```
class A; def initalize(varl); end; end;
a = A.new("asd")
 => #<A:0x007fab7c2fe250>
```

What is that "#"? What I want is an object inside a hash, that, for example, behaves like a string. Like this:

```
hash = {str: A.new("asd")}
hash[:str]  # => "asd"
hash[:str].my_method
```

How can I do that? I don't want to inherit from String. I want to do this for some other types with other representations too.

Update:

What i really want to do is to build a Hash where the keys and the values are "some kind of" Integers, Strings and Arrays but have my own defined methods:

```
hash = {a: MyArray.new([:x,:y]), b: MyString.new("asdasd")}
hash[:a] # => [:x,:y]
hash[:b] # => "asdasd"
hash[:b].my_method
```

In fact, the hash should be serializable for ActiveRecord.

//Edit:
I found out what i acutally searched for:

There is no "value" in genereal. What i looked for in my question was the behaviour of an object in terms of some methods.

If i want any general object to behave "like an array", in my mind there were things that i thought of:
- accessing contents via array[] and array << entry and array.push(entry) or array.map{block}.

And i found out that is very bad to just inherit from Array. A much better apporach is to use forwardable and and forward these methods to an attribute of that object.

For example:

```
class Answer::Array
  attr_accessor :value

  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :@value, :inspect
  def_delegator :@value, :to_s
  def_delegator :@value, :[]
  def_delegator :@value, :[]=
  def_delegator :@value, :each
  def_delegator :@value, :map

  def initlialize
    @value = []
  end

  def my_method
    some_code
  end
end
```

So to let an object behave like any other "primitive" object, just use Forwardable to delegate methods to a value object.

Answer (score 4):

The string representation comes from a method named `inspect`, which represents your object in a string format.

```
class A
  def initialize(varl)
    @varl = varl
  end
  def inspect
    "An instance of A containing #{@varl.inspect}"
  end
end

A.new "abc"         # => An instance of A containing "abc"
{key: A.new("abc")} # => {:key=>An instance of A containing "abc"}

class A
  def inspect
    @varl.inspect
  end
end
a = A.new "abc"
a # => "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just called `#to_s` on the object when you do `h[:str]`

You can simulate this with you own class by doing:

```
1.9.3p392 :012 > class A
1.9.3p392 :013?>   attr_accessor :varl
1.9.3p392 :014?>   def initialize(varl)
1.9.3p392 :015?>     self.varl = varl
1.9.3p392 :016?>   end
1.9.3p392 :017?>   def to_s
1.9.3p392 :018?>     varl
1.9.3p392 :019?>   end
1.9.3p392 :020?> end
 => nil 
1.9.3p392 :021 > h = {str: A.new("asd") }
 => {:str=>asd} 
1.9.3p392 :023 > h[:str]
 => asd
```

Comment: So, what how does the hash know, if to call t_s or to_a or to_i? I mean: it could also a kind of Objects that i want to be representated as an array.

Comment: Everything has `#to_s`, it's defined in `Object`.  So it will always be `#to_s`.

Comment: I think `#inspect` is called.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the “value” of an object in ruby?

It depends on the object. You define it when you define a class.
What irb shows after each statement, is not the "value" of an object. It's a string representation of the resulting object.

> What is this "asd"?

It's the result of *object*.to_s, where *object* is the resulting object of your last statement.
Object is an abstract concept, and in order to show it, it needs to be converted to something you can see, which is a string in this case. It's irb that converted the object to string (by to_s method) so that you can see and understand it.

> What is that "#"?

Your new class doesn't have its own to_s method, and the to_s method of one of the ancestors was called. I think it was of Module class, which returns "#<*class-name*:*pointer-to-the-object*>"

What I want is an object inside a hash, that behaves like a string. How can I do that?

Define to_s method in your class.